# Does Amazon Lumberyard support AR yet?

Tags: augmented-reality, plugin, lumberyard-engine

I would like some help regarding whether Amazon Lumberyard supports augmented reality (AR) or not. It clearly mentions VR is supported but nothing about AR support. It looks as if we just have to attach an AR plugin on engines like unreal, unity, etc. So will it work here?

Comment: If you're new here and don't want to risk being off-topic, please follow http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour ;)

Comment: @Bart thanks for taking the time to help a complete n00b! :D

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Lumberyard (I do have some experience with its Cryengine base), but I would guess this requires a custom plugin. I however don't know if other parties have already written some, or if Cryengine plugins are compatible.

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2016 there is no native, in-engine support specifically for augmented reality in Lumberyard.

You'd have to build it yourself or use a third-party solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!! Could you also please suggest a few third party solutions? Please also tell me how long would it take to build a custom plugin. Thanks.

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy I'm afraid not, as those questions ("which thing to use" and "how long will this take") are not considered on-topic here (see the [help]).